# Why RegEx lets add more than 1 slash?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^check/([^\/]+)/?$ check.php?id=$1 [L]
```

When I go to check/connected////,  check.php displays it as connected. But, from my understanding of the rewrite rule, if I add more than 1 trailing slash to connected, it should not match.

Check.php:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['id'];
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us exactly what does `check.php` displays ?

Comment: when url is localhost/check/something//// it displays something i think it shouldnt work cuz i exclude slash in the class and add only one optional leading slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that multiple `/` are **stripped down to single `/`** while matching a URL regex in `RewriteRule`. That's the reason you are seeing this behavior.

If you want to match multiple `/` (let's say 2 or more) then you should use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+check/[^/]+/{2,}
```

Comment: u got me wrong i dont want to match multiple slashes i want connected//// not to match but it matches

Comment: That was just an example. Even if you want to avoid matching multiple `//` you will still have to rely on `%{THE_REQUEST}` because of the reason stated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the way between the browser and the server, consecutive slashes are condensed into one. After all, under the normal circumstances of referencing a filename, it makes no sense to have more than one slash in a row.

For this reason, your `.htaccess` is only seeing one slash, right at the end, instead of however many you actually typed. This is why your RewriteRule works, and also why the outcome is just "connected" without any extra slashes.